# How to access man pages as structured content

Tags: command-line, man, documentation, groff, roff

I'm building a resource that references man pages, and I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way to access man pages as **structured** data? My current approach is to do a *lot* if REGEXing, but this is tedious and prone to errors.

I'm not an expert on *nix, but what I understand about man pages is that they are basically text files with a particular syntax that is parsable by the `man` command. This makes me a little skeptical that there might be an easy way to, say, access a list of the options or flags. But maybe there's a way to do it that I don't know.

Comment: More specifically, text files containing instructions to be parsed by some variant of `troff` with the `an`, `doc`, or `andoc` macro packages.  Because it's a macro language.  Which means, in general, if you want to extract content then you need to be able to parse the macros

Answer (score 6):

You might peek at how the [fish shell](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell) builds its [completions from the man pages](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/blob/master/share/completions/man.fish) in particular how `__fish_complete_man` works. An easier option assuming `groff` might be to emit HTML and then use one of the multitude of HTML parsers out there to get what you want:

```
$ groff -T html -mdoc xpquery.1 | xpquery -p HTML '//p[b="xpquery"][2]' -
<p style="margin-left:17%;"><b>xpquery</b>
[<b>−E </b><i>encoding</i>]
[<b>−n </b><i>namespace</i>]
[<b>−p </b><i>method</i>]
[<b>−S </b><i>xpath-subquery</i>]
[<b>−t </b><i>timeout</i>] <i>xpath-query
file-or-url ..</i></p>
$
```

That's [a man page](https://github.com/thrig/scripts/blob/master/misc/xpquery.1) rendered as HTML and then selected on using [XPath](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev) to obtain the list of flags in the SYNOPSIS section; using CSS selectors might be more hip these days. However, the HTML generated is not very structured.

Answer (score 3):

Man pages are [roff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roff_(computer_program)) formatted text files, which unfortunately is one of the most irritating to parse formatting languages around right now.  You may have some luck pulling out what you want by looking through the documentation for whatever roff implementation your system uses (it will almost always be one of `nroff`, `troff`, or `groff`).  The format itself is somewhat complicated (it was designed in an era when minimalism was the epitome of good software design), but the structure of most man pages is reasonably consistent, so it shouldn't be too hard.

In addition to that, you have a couple of other options.  The first is to look at the sources for the man pages in the software's source distribution.  Most software these days compiles their man pages to the roff sources parsed by the man program from some other format, most of which are far easier to parse than roff macros.  The other is to look into tools (including `groff`) which convert man pages to other formats, as suggested in thrig's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [manServer](https://github.com/silviuvulcan/manServer) which is a perl script from 1999 that parses man pages in a simple way and presents them as web pages. It has all the perl code you need to interpret the troff source.

Answer (score 0):

[Doclifter](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/doclifter/), in particular its [manlifter](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/doclifter/manlifter.html) script, will convert troff and a number of troff macro sets into XML-[Docbook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DocBook).